# Evaluating forward references with typing.get_type_hints in Python for a class defined inside another method/class

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.10

I'm having trouble calling typing.get_type_hints() for classes that have forward references as strings. My code works with not defined inside of a function. I've reproduced a minimal example below in Python 3.10:

```py
import typing
class B:
  pass
class A:
  some_b: "B" 
print(typing.get_type_hints(A)) # prints {'some_b': <class '__main__.B'>}
```

```py
import typing
def func():
  class B:
    pass
  class A:
    some_b: "B" 
  print(typing.get_type_hints(A)) 
func() # NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there any way to get around this, and make sure that forward references with strings get evaluated in the correct scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) allows you to explicitly pass the local namespace to use for resolving references via the `localns` parameter.

```py
from typing import get_type_hints


def func():
    class A:
        some_b: "B"

    class B:
        pass

    print(get_type_hints(A, localns=locals()))


func()
```

Output: `{'some_b': <class '__main__.func.<locals>.B'>}`

See the docs for [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).

---

Side note: By utilizing postponed evaluation of annotations ([PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/)) you can omit the quotation marks:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import get_type_hints


def func():
    class A:
        some_b: B

    class B:
        pass

    print(get_type_hints(A, localns=locals()))
```